# Programming Project Sensor Listener Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

Good morning/night/evening ?

So, I'am a student in Bioinformatics and I have a project for the end of this scolar year. I have to listen the rotation vector sensor into an Android smartphone and send the data through Wifi to a Python server which will process the data.

I read a lot about android and socket but I'm a real newbie in Android programming. So my idea was to use a socket running in an AsyncTask and a class listening to the rotation vector. But I am not very sure about the way to implement this listener and send the data from my Listener class to my socket AsyncTask.

Actually I have no code it is just a question to have some recommendations about the best way to do this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I did something similar with meteor js a as a prof of concept but using JavaScript and the Android Browser using websockets and some Meteor Magic.

For example : 
Go with your computer browser at this site url : http://poc.tiberiucorbu.ro/orientationpaint/display
Go with your mobile at this url : http://poc.tiberiucorbu.ro/orientationpaint/device

There is also a protocol meant to be super light with realtime speed named `mtqq`. With this protocol Python can act as a server and 
In android as a client.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I look at your pages and that is pretty good stuff. Do you know how to send data from an AsyncTask running a socket and another one which is listening to sensor data ? I don't know if using Handler is the best way to do this.

Comment: You mean two android devices one that sends data and another one that listens?

Comment: Nope I am sending data from an Android client to a Python server through socket.

Comment: Look at this :  http://techtej.blogspot.de/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html. Shows how to communicate between two threads. Basically what you'll be needing for your task. And yes, it uses Androids Handler, Sorry I don't have now  time to write an example.